# Inequalities for the sine function and for a definite integeral of $x^{-1}\sin x$

Tags: calculus

1. $\sin x\leq x-\frac{x^3}{3\pi},$when $\displaystyle x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.
2. $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^3}{144}\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\leq \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{72}$$

this question，i do not know how to start. can anybody give me some hints？thank you very much!

Comment: mean value theorem

Comment: could you pls give me more details？

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

a) Define $f:[0,\pi/2] \to \Bbb R$ by $f(x) = \sin x - x + \frac{x^3}{3\pi}$, check that $f(0) \leq 0$ and that $f'(x) \leq 0$ in $[0,\pi/2]$.

b) Use Taylor expansion for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and find lower and upper bound for it. Then apply $\int_0^{\pi/2}$.

Comment: it's not clear that$f′(x)=cosx -1+\frac{x^2}{\pi}\leq0$

Comment: @Wheea Is it not clear that the function $f'(x)$ is equal to that expression? Or that it's $\le 0$?

Comment: the function  $f′(x)\leq0$@Axoren

Comment: the question is how to prove the expression $\frac{x^2}{\pi}-1+cosx \leq 0$,i have tried a lot, but couldn't find a way to go.@Axoren